# Exporting Lotus Notes / Domino Mailbox

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

What Can I do in order to export every single Mailbox there is on one or multiple Lotus Domino Servers. AFAIK you can only export Mailbox via the Client (Structured Text, Tabular etc.) This would leave me with having to manually open (too many) Mailboxes.

Export Format doesn't really matter as long as I can get the important Information out. ( From, To, Date, Attachment ?!, Message, Subject, CCs etc.)

EDIT: **Asking this because we want to migrate emails to a different target system**

Comment: Is this for backup purposes, or do you need to extract and work with the contents from each mailbox? If for a simple backup, you can just copy the NSF files from the filesystem on the server, but it's not clear if this is what you're after. Are you migrating from Domino to another 3rd party system like Exchange?

Comment: @CPR yes effectively I am migrating to another Solution but i dont really have specific requirements for the target System. So any plain export format would be fine ( csv, html, eml whatever really as long as i can work with it). Email-File Attachments would be really great as well.

Comment: There are commercial tools available for this, or this article might help you: http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Exporting-email-from-Lotus-Notes-to-EML-messages. There's some LotusScript on that post that can export emails as .EML files. Note that I haven't tested this myself, but it looks like it should do the job. I'm sure you can modify the script for your needs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. For example you can setup IMAP on Domino server and then download all messages from specific mailboxes to EML format. Or even better you can directly copy message from Domino to other IMAP enabled mail server. For example you can try to use this: https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync.